# axios, array parameters and CORS

Tags: javascript, cors, axios

I'm using axios with quasar/vue.
`axios.post(this.serverUrl, null, {params: {blah: "test"}}`
params are 3rd parameter. I saw it should be 2nd but when it was, I got the following:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://example.com' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

When it's the 3rd parameter all was good.

All was good until I needed to pass an array of jsons, for example:
`var info = [{name: "test", age: 40},{name: "tester", age: 50}]`
No matter what I tried, including using qs: `axios.post(this.serverUrl, null, {params: {dataToSend: info},paramsSerializer: params => { return qs.stringify(params)}` and another parsing method

```
parseParams(params) {
      const keys = Object.keys(params);
      let options = '';
      keys.forEach((key) => {
        const isParamTypeObject = typeof params[key] === 'object';
        const isParamTypeArray = isParamTypeObject && (params[key].length >= 0);
        if (!isParamTypeObject) {
          options += `${key}=${params[key]}&`;
        }
        if (isParamTypeObject && isParamTypeArray) {      
          params[key].forEach((element) => {
            options += `${key}=${element}&`;
          });
        }      
      });
      return options ? options.slice(0, -1) : options;
    },
```

I started receiving the above error of CORS.

My guess is that the parsing is wrong but I couldn't figure out how to overcome this, even after reading the so many examples on the web. My server expects to receive an array of jsons like the above `[{name: "test", age: 40},{name: "tester", age: 50}]` so I need the client to send it as such. I'm using axios 0.19.1

What am I missing? Thanks!

**Update:**

```
"/api": {
    target: "https://myrealdomain.com:8443",
    changeOrigin: true,          
    pathRewrite: {
        "^/api": "/mysuffix1/mysuffix2"
    }
}
```

and calling `axios.post("api", {...})` works, but in real life the files will sit on the same place as the server https://myrealdomain.com and I don't need the API suffix, only mysuffix1/mysuffix2.

Can I simulate changeOrigin in dev to be just as prod?

Answer (score 2):

If you plan to eventually deploy your Quasar app on the same domain name as the API's that your calling, you can avoid the need for CORS rules on this API server during development on `localhost:8080` by configuring proxy rules. When you spin up Quasar in **development** mode using ...

$ quasar dev

It launches the [WebPack Dev server](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/).  This server can be configured via `quasar.config.js`.  The Dev server includes a proxy API that can be invoked via calls from your app to `localhost:8080` which then forwards them to `example.com`, changing the domain name in your API requests via this setting: `changeOrigin: true`.  Now your API server at `example.com` sees requests that appear to come from the same origin domain so no CORS rules are needed!

```
devServer: {
  // https: true,
  port: 8080,
  open: true, // opens browser window automatically
 // set up one or more proxy rules
  proxy: {
    // Proxy requests prefixed by /api URL
    "/api": {
      target: "https://example.com",
      changeOrigin: true,  // Avoids the need for CORS rule on your API server
      // Optionally map /api to the same or a different path on the API server
      pathRewrite: {
        "^/api": "api"
      }
    }
  }
},
```

For more info refer to ...

- [API Proxying in the Quasar docs](https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli/cli-documentation/api-proxying)
- [WebPack Dev Server](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/)
- [How to inspect Network XHR API requests using Chrome DevTools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network)

Comment: Eventually it will be installed on the same server as the service itself. Now it's localhsot calling that server/service for testing phase. the changeOrigin is just for "quasar dev" mode? I ask because other requests work, only this one isn't, this is why I think the problem is with the parsing of the array.

Comment: Yes ... the proxy rules only apply for `quasar dev` mode. I'm sure you've inspected the network Request / Response values. Check JSON encoding in the network request/responses in Chrome Debugger. Check headers (try sending the same using PostMan or PostWoman ;) ).  See if you can isolate the cause .. might be the proxy causing some issue OR your API server.  If you have CORS rules enabled then you might need to allow specific headers.

Comment: I will check more thoroughly when I'm back to the computer. Yesterday I did check and the params were , for example: &data=<encoded object>&data=<encoded object>etc... Will my server receive is as a json array? I will be surprised if it will. Anwyay, later today I will post here an eaxmple of the request after changing the proxy.

Comment: devServer: {
      https: true, // if set to false, the page loads, if set to true, page is not loaded,
      port: 8080,
      open: true,
      proxy: {
        "/": {
          target: "https://myrealdomain.com:8443/api/api",
          changeOrigin: true,  // Avoids the need for CORS rule on your API server
          pathRewrite: {
            "^/": ""
          }
        }
      }      

I still receive the same error of CROS

Comment: Just to make sure: the client runs on localhost:8080 and is calling myrealdomain.com:8443/api/api

Comment: pleas read my update above, I think I'm almost there... Thanks

Comment: Your client code should not call `myrealdomain.com:8443/api` (since that's cross origin and will trigger CORS issue), instead you can just call the proxy server that's `localhost:8080/api/...` which will forward your request to `myrealdomain.com:8443/api` which should prevent the CORS error.  Actually the client code can just use `/api` it does not need to reference the host name since that should default to the host the client code was loaded from ... that ensures it will work in development and final deployment.

Comment: I don't think you need to use `/api/api`

Answer (score 0):

You will have to enable CORS in your API/Web service. See this question for answer:

[Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'API_URL' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56831813/access-to-xmlhttprequest-at-api-url-from-origin-http-localhost8080-has-be)

Comment: So how come all my other requests went well with no problem? I still think it's something related to the parsing that is causing it. Having said that: The CORS is just so localhost could communicate? I ask because localhost is just for the testing

Comment: Your question says `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://example.com' `. Have you verified it is going to intended server?

Comment: example.com is a placeholder for the real domain name.